# Ajax routes in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In my Rails 2.3 application, the following routes were working properly

```
map.ajax 'ajax', :controller => 'widgetresponse_controller'   , :action => 'getWidgetJson'
```

When I migrated to Rails 3,
I tried a number of new routes, to get this working but none of them worked.

1.

```
match 'ajax' => 'widgetresponse#getWidgetJson', :as => :ajax
```

2.

```
match 'ajax' => 'widgetresponse_controller#getWidgetJson', :as => :ajax
```

3.

```
get 'widgetresponse/getWidgetJson', :as => :ajax
```

4.

```
get 'widgetresponse/getWidgetJson'
```

Its a very basic question to ask, but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: why does your controller look like: widgetresponse_controller in your Rails 2.x route?

Comment: @polarblau: Yes, it doesn't find the route and shows: Routing Error

No route matches "/widgetresponse/getWidgetJson/1"

Comment: @apneadiving: In my controller code, I return a json object. I don't think it has got anything to do with my problem

Comment: why do you need a route for this? I don't think I ever used routes for my project's ajax calls.

Comment: @cbrulak: If i don't use an ajax call, how would I pass my parameters in the ajax call to the method in the controller, which is going to use it. If you are able to do that, can you show a gist of what you did?

Comment: I would run `rake routes` after setting it each way. Then, you'll be able to see better what it's producing and maybe why it's different than you expected.  I agree with cbrulak though.  You should just be able to use normal routes like the ones you use for your HTML pages, but you use `respond_to` and `format.js` to respond with javascript or json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
match "/widgetresponse/getWidgetJson/:id" => "widgetresponse#getWidgetJson"
```

Comment: @polarblu: I know the above route but here I am hard-coding that my ajax call from the view will send only 1 parameter to the action. Someday later, If i want to send 2 more parameters, I would have to come back to my routes file and change the route definition to make it work again, which is not in the case of an ajax call, as you don't mention anywhere in the routes the parameters you are passing.

Comment: But how are the parameters important for your routing? Not knowing your design, I'm wondering what your accessing within the widgetresponse controller? This can't be a resource then, right? And you're not really using an RESTful approach either?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was a bit puzzled then and after a while, your soln. made perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that may have happened before is that things were falling through to the default route which was removed in Ruby on Rails 3 (good idea).

I found this guide:

http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/

really helpful with lot of yummy new rails 3 options.

Comment: I went through the article when I was facing the problem, but there is no mention as to how to write a route for an AJAX call. Thanks anyway, for sharing the article. I'm sure it'll help someone struggling with routes in Rails3.

Comment: Thanks.  Your ajax calls should be pretty identical to regular ones.  I believe the major difference is juust in "what" gets returns and with AJAX it's often something like JSON for a message, etc, rather than a full page reload, but that gets done in the controller with responds_to/responds_with (rails3 syntax).

Comment: so perhaps your issue is just rails2 -> rails3, not ajax

Comment: I just re-read polarblau's answer and your comment.  Perhaps the issue for you is that maybe you're mixing the id with other query parameters that can just be passed on the right of the "?" when needed and then used as params[:the_param_name] in your controller.

Comment: Perhaps this route example:  match "/:year(/:month(/:day))" => "info#about" will help.  At the end of the day if you are having custom routes and names like this, then yes you may just have to change routes and again with rails3 the default 'catchall' will not work as perhaps it did in rails2.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the explanation. My issue was that when I was upgrading the app from rails2 -> 3, there was no documentation on the web as to how re-write ajax routes. So, I struggled a bit for a while, until I found a working soln. and moved on with it.